# Which methods apply best in the analysis of non-linear phenomena?

Tags: fourier-analysis, nonlinear-analysis, nonlinear-dynamics, wavelets

I am going to set up my Bachelors project in analysis of non-linear wave phenomena, and I am planning to study plots and graphs of nonlinear spectra.

In this context, I am quite familiar with the Fourier transform, however, does anyone here know of other methods too, such as Lebesgue integral, or other methods that can be used on analytic nonlinear functions of these spectra so to find common pattern among them, and also quantify their magnitudes and norms?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Moo, and nice to see you again!

Comment: Great paper, I have downloaded it. But are there no more "common" ways that you are aware of? For instance, integration is an important method studied in functional analysis, are you aware of other operations on some function that play an important role in nonlinear analysis of exactly wavelets?

Comment: Thanks! I will check out the first and then the second source in detail! Have a good day Moo